# How android's BaseAdapter notifyDataSetChanged method work?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, android-adapter, notify

In the document for the method `notifyDataSetChanged` of class `BaseAdapter` noted that *"Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself."*

Supposed I changed the 3rd element in my string array (array data for the `ListView`), what *"any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself"* means ? Does the 3rd view item in my list view be notified ?

Also, how is `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `getView()` concerned ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Supposed I changed the 3rd element in my string array (array data for
>   the listview), what "any View reflecting the data set should refresh
>   itself" means ?

It means that any view which shows/is based on/uses that data(the string array in your case) should be invalidated(remeasured, redrawn) in order to show the user the new set of data.

> Does the 3rd view item in my list view be notified?

No, the parent `ListView` will be notified. When you set the adapter on a `ListView`, an observer(from the `ListView`) will be set for that adapter. Calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter will announce that observer from the `ListView` that something has happen to the data. At this moment the `ListView` will recreate the rows to show the new data.

> Also, how is notifyDataSetChanged() and getView() concerned ?

I'm not sure I understand what you ask. The `getView` method of an adapter is used by the `ListView` to obtain a new row each time this is required. When you call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter this will trigger the observer in the `ListView`. As it's time to recreate the list, the `ListView` will call the `getView` method of the adapter to show the necessary number of rows(the ones visible on the screen). So each time you call `notifyDataSetChanged` the `getView` method will be called for the visible rows.

Comment: When I call notifyDataSetChanged, getView is not called sometimes. How is this possible?